# React Component hook variable will not update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, hoisting

I have a React component that gets data from a parent page/component. I use this data object (`jobData`) to populate a hook variable value when the component (a modal) is fired. The `jobData` looks like this: `[{id: '17003', file_name: 'My_File', type: 'Medium', state: 'Arkansas'}]`. In the browser debugger, I can see the `jobData` getting passed into the component, but when it gets to `return ....<TextField  .... value={productID}` the `productID` says `undefined`! Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I want the `TextField` to display the value of `jobData[0]['id']` when it fires and then store the value of `productID` when it cahnges.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, TextField, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogTitle, Modal, 
FormControl, Select, InputLabel } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function ScheduleProdsModal({jobData}) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    // Below is the hook with problems
    let [productID, setProductID] = useState(jobData[0]["id"]);

    return (
        <div>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Button color="neutral" variant="contained" cursor="pointer" onClick={handleOpen}>Schedule Products</Button>
                <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                    <DialogTitle>Schedule Products</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent >
                        <FormControl fullWidth style={{marginTop: '5px', marginBottom: '5px'}}>
                            <TextField
                              autoFocus
                              margin="dense"
                              width="100%"
                              id="my_id"
                              label="My ID"
                              type="text"
                              value={productID}
                              variant="outlined"
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                setProductID(e.target.value);
                              }}
                            />
                        </FormControl>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions style={{marginRight: 'inherit'}}>
                        <Button color="neutral" variant="contained" cursor="pointer" onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
                        <Button color="neutral" variant="contained" cursor="pointer" onClick={handleScheduler}>Schedule</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </div>  
    );
}
```

Comment: You are only initializing `productID` with `jobData[0]["id"]`. Without showing the code I can only guess, but I'm gonna put my money on the fact that `jobData` is empty/undefined on the initial render. If it's changed later on, that won't update `productID`.

Comment: As @super is hinting at, you should avoid initializing state with data from props, because if the props change the state will not. Look to hoist the state to the parent component and/or pass down callbacks

Comment: Do you get the jobData array at some point in the lifecycle of this `ScheduleProdsModal` component?

Comment: To answer the above question 1) When the parent component page is loaded, `jobData` is set to `const [jobData, setJobData] = useState("JobData for Product Page");` It is updated using `setJobData` when the use clicks on a row in a table and then gets passed to my `ScheduleProdsModal` component. 2) Yes, the `jobData` array get passed when the modal is launched. When it fires (via button click),  `jobData` looks like this `[{id: '17003', file_name: 'My_File', type: 'Medium', state: 'Arkansas'}]`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have set jobData array when initialising the projectId, which will be undefined in the first load unless it has been handled in the parent component. Therefore as a workaround we normally use `useEffect` hook to get the upcoming props changes. So, when the `jobData` array is not null, you can use `setProductID` to get the relevant product id inside the `useEffect` hook. For the time period that you are not getting the data, you can use your favourite loading mechanism to show a loading screen. Find the below code snippet.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
// Below is the hook with problems
let [productID, setProductID] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  if(jobData && jobData.length > 0){
    setProductID(Number(jobData[0]["id"]))
  }
}, [jobData])

// You can put more conditions like undefined and null checking if you want
if(productID === 0){
  // Use your fav loading page or loader here
  return <>Loading...</>      
}

return (
    <div>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

Hope this would help.